# recurse through json in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a sample json:

[image]

I want to use the json module of python and recurse through to find the "MaxSize" in "pevcwebasg". Have the following code:

import json

```
param_file_handle = json.load(open("sample.json"))
print param_file_handle['Resources']['pevcwebasg']['Type']
resources = param_file_handle['Resources']
for asg in resources:
     print asg["Type"]
```

The out put of which is :

```
> AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup Traceback (most recent call last): 
> File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
>     print asg['Type'] TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

What I dont get is this line "print param_file_handle['Resources']['pevcwebasg']['Type']" works fine and gets me the output but when i recurse through and try and find asg["Type"], it fails. Any better way to do this ? I need to recurse through the tree and find the value.

**Edit 1:**

as I do recurse through values, I get stuck with error.

```
param_file_handle = json.load(open("sample.json"))
resources = param_file_handle['Resources']
for asg in resources.values():
     if asg["Type"] == "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup":
          for values in asg['Properties']:
              print values["MaxSize"]
```

error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    print values["MaxSize"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: next time, please paste text instead of posting pictures

Comment: it was a huge json, didn't want it to take the whole space so just used the pic. I know I could have trimmed it. Will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for asg in resources:
```

This iterates through the keys of `resources`, rather than the values. Try:

```
for asg in resources.values():
```

Comment: I would do keys() instead of values() so you have the option to reproduce the content of the key which meets your Criteria.

Comment: @rajesh.kanakabandi and owner of the post - take a look at the edit

Comment: you dont need the inner for loop. when you want to Access the MaxSize.

Answer (score 1):

```
param_file_handle = json.load(open("sample.json"))
resources = param_file_handle['Resources']
for asg in resources.values():
     if asg["Type"] == "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup":
          print asg["Properties"]["MaxSize"]
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

you broke hirerchy, missed "pevcwebasg"

```
resources = param_file_handle['Resources']['pevcwebasg']
for asg in resources:
     print asg["Type"]
```